# My Device is not detected to test my Android App

Tags: android

I am trying to test my application in My phone. 
I am following this link. 
[Link](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html)

But Device is not showing in Device Chooser. 
I am using Sony xperia Sola to test my app.

But if I use micromax A089, It is working fine. Why my Sony is not working. Please let me any idea.

Comment: You use my answer? Why i have a negative vote?

Comment: Not by me @JoãoMarcos..

Answer (score 0):

Try these solutions -

- Try to reset the adb (DDMS Perspective --> Devices Tab --> Small
  Triangle on right side(Last option) --> Reset adb)
- USB Debugging should be ON
- Open Task Manager and kill all the process that are adb.exe and then
  restart the eclipse and start adb again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the drivers of your phone are not installed, Installing [Mobogeine](http://www.mobogenie.com/) might help to detect your device!